# ActiveMQ Artemis not starting on Windows 10: Failed to bind acceptor

Tags: windows, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I downloaded the zip from https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/ and unzipped it. Then I ran

```
 artemis.cmd create broker2
```

I changed to the bin folder of broker2 and ran

```
artemis.cmd run
```

I tried it a lot of time, I restarted several times and tried again, I tried as administrator, I ran `netstat -anb` and verified nothing is running on port 1883, still the result is always:

```
D:\apache-artemis-2.15.0\bin\broker2\bin>artemis.cmd run
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/D:/apache-artemis-2.15.0/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15.0


Sep. 16, 2020 4:00:07 NACHM. java.lang.System$LoggerFinder lambda$accessProvider$0
WARNING: Failed to instantiate LoggerFinder provider; Using default.
2020-09-16 16:00:07,668 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2020-09-16 16:00:08,288 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2020-09-16 16:00:08,312 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2020-09-16 16:00:08,343 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 536.870.912
2020-09-16 16:00:08,363 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2020-09-16 16:00:08,365 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2020-09-16 16:00:08,366 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2020-09-16 16:00:08,367 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2020-09-16 16:00:08,367 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2020-09-16 16:00:08,368 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2020-09-16 16:00:08,438 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
2020-09-16 16:00:08,439 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2020-09-16 16:00:09,607 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2020-09-16 16:00:09,669 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2020-09-16 16:00:09,750 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2020-09-16 16:00:09,774 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2020-09-16 16:00:10,542 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2020-09-16 16:00:10,553 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2020-09-16 16:00:10,564 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started NIO Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2020-09-16 16:00:10,581 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224104: Error starting the Acceptor mqtt {scheme=tcp, tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576, port=1883, host=0.0.0.0, protocols=MQTT, useEpoll=true, tcpSendBufferSize=1048576}
2020-09-16 16:00:10,581 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor mqtt to 0.0.0.0:1883
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor.startServerChannels(NettyAcceptor.java:688) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor.start(NettyAcceptor.java:456) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl.startAcceptors(RemotingServiceImpl.java:313) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.completeActivation(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3090) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:78) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:603) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:530) [artemis-server-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:61) [artemis-cli-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:90) [artemis-cli-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:153) [artemis-cli-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:101) [artemis-cli-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:128) [artemis-cli-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [java.base:]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) [java.base:]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134) [artemis-boot.jar:2.15.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50) [artemis-boot.jar:2.15.0]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:219) [java.base:]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]

2020-09-16 16:00:10,586 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.15.0 [0.0.0.0, nodeID=edecc73f-f824-11ea-bed7-309c236ea6f2]
2020-09-16 16:00:10,857 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2020-09-16 16:00:10,956 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2020-09-16 16:00:11,936 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2020-09-16 16:00:11,961 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2020-09-16 16:00:11,962 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to hawtio 1.5.12 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2020-09-16 16:00:11,969 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager] Using file upload directory: D:\apache-artemis-2.15.0\bin\broker2\tmp\uploads
2020-09-16 16:00:11,982 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2020-09-16 16:00:12,002 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/D:/apache-artemis-2.15.0/bin/broker2/etc/\jolokia-access.xml]
2020-09-16 16:00:12,229 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control
2020-09-16 16:00:12,629 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ProxyWhitelist] Initial proxy whitelist: [localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.180.120, pc10.procheck24.de, 172.17.2.161, pc10.mshome.net]
2020-09-16 16:00:12,783 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8161
2020-09-16 16:00:12,784 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia
2020-09-16 16:00:12,785 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
2020-09-16 16:00:13,086 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services
2020-09-16 16:00:13,088 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter
2020-09-16 16:00:13,234 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin
2020-09-16 16:00:13,245 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin
2020-09-16 16:00:13,263 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.15.0 [edecc73f-f824-11ea-bed7-309c236ea6f2] stopped, uptime 5.570 seconds
org.apache.activemq.artemis.component.WebTmpCleaner:Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:../config/logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\config\logging.properties (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden))
```

What is missing to run a broker on a windows machine?

Comment: Is there a corresponding stack-trace?

Comment: I just put the lines I deemed relevant first but added the whole thing now @JustinBertram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root "Caused by" is this:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:219) [java.base:]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
```

Here the JVM is working with the OS to bind a server socket to `0.0.0.0:1883`. This operation is failing ostensibly because something is already bound to that address & port. This is an environmental issue between the JVM and the OS. It's not something the broker can overcome directly. The only thing you could do from the broker's perspective is to change the port, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:81883?protocols=MQTT</acceptor>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, see my answer. The problem is, that nothing was using port 1883. As I said in the answer, I ran netstat, I used another windows tool, and they all showed that nothing was using port 1883. (netstat -anp | grep 1883 comes back empty)

Comment: Clearly that's not what the OS is reporting to the JVM. Perhaps their is a bug in the OS or the JVM. Have you tried a different JVM?

Comment: I had java 10.0.2. I tried openjdk 12.0.1, with exactly the same result.

Comment: That suggests something weird going on with Windows itself. Perhaps there's an internal service holding that port or some kind of security restriction that's manifesting as this `BindException`.

Answer (score 2):

I have got this problem few times on my development machine (Windows 10).
No application working on port but AMQ could not acquire it.

I have no idea why problem occurred - I could not reproduce it on purpose.

For me restarting Windows has solved the issue.
I has been also trying logging out user as it (I think) it should kill user processes but with no effect.
Maybe there has been some issue with releasing port after improper AMQ closure?

Comment: I have Artemis 2.20.0 and jdk-17.0.1 and restart also solved the issue. I think I hadn't restarted my machine after the jdk was installed but I'm not shure.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:4785?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
```

I changed the port of MQTT in broker2/etc/broker.xml to a random number and it worked, the broker was able to start. I still have no clue why port 1883 was not accessible (I also tried 1884 and it did not work either).

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem. I've replaced the server address 0.0.0.0 by 127.0.0.1 (warning, it is not the same though but for local test, it's fine) in the broker.xml configuration and it works like a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

the process with ID 5672 is preventing startup

**check process on port 5672 and kill it**

netstat -ano|findstr 5672

taskkill /f /pid PID

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).