# AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor artemis to localhost:61616

Tags: message-queue, activemq-artemis

I got the below error while starting ActiveMQ Artemis. Yesterday it was working fine. I was trying to run it on my local Windows 10 machine. To solve this issue I have tried many solutions like:

1. Try deleting folder `data`, `log`, and `tmp`.
2. In `broker.xml` tried to change the port.
3. Tried  creating new broker.
4. Also tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.
5. Checked if any service is running off the port, but none of the services is running on port `61616`.

None of the solutions work.

```
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0


2023-06-09 20:43:07,851 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server version 2.28.0
2023-06-09 20:43:07,885 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2023-06-09 20:43:14,556 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2023-06-09 20:43:14,574 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222007: Security risk! Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the cluster chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis User Guide for instructions on how to change this.
2023-06-09 20:43:14,594 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1073741824
2023-06-09 20:43:14,627 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2023-06-09 20:43:14,627 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2023-06-09 20:43:14,628 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2023-06-09 20:43:14,628 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2023-06-09 20:43:14,629 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2023-06-09 20:43:14,629 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2023-06-09 20:43:14,822 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-06-09 20:43:14,823 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2023-06-09 20:43:14,828 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2023-06-09 20:43:14,829 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2023-06-09 20:43:15,150 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224104: Error starting the Acceptor artemis {scheme=tcp, tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576, port=61616, host=localhost, protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE, useEpoll=true, tcpSendBufferSize=1048576}
2023-06-09 20:43:15,151 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor artemis to localhost:61616
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor.startServerChannels(NettyAcceptor.java:735) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor.start(NettyAcceptor.java:531) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl.startAcceptors(RemotingServiceImpl.java:315) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.completeActivation(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3516) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedNothingLiveActivation.run(SharedNothingLiveActivation.java:121) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:708) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:605) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:66) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:129) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:212) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:162) ~[artemis-cli-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:144) ~[artemis-boot.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:61) ~[artemis-boot.jar:2.28.0]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:141) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
2023-06-09 20:43:15,160 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.28.0 [localhost, nodeID=4c0536c4-067e-11ee-8668-646c806f3233]
2023-06-09 20:43:15,167 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2023-06-09 20:43:15,456 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2023-06-09 20:43:15,585 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2023-06-09 20:43:16,289 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2023-06-09 20:43:16,296 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2023-06-09 20:43:16,298 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.15.0
2023-06-09 20:43:16,302 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2023-06-09 20:43:16,308 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2023-06-09 20:43:16,318 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2023-06-09 20:43:16,323 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/D:/artemis-cluster/master-slave/master/etc/\jolokia-access.xml]
2023-06-09 20:43:16,415 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8161
2023-06-09 20:43:16,416 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia
2023-06-09 20:43:16,417 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
2023-06-09 20:43:16,421 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor] Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.assertOpen(ServerLocatorImpl.java:1816) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:646) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:547) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:526) ~[artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.ClusterController$ConnectRunnable.run(ClusterController.java:501) ~[artemis-server-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
2023-06-09 20:43:16,566 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241005: Stopping embedded web server
2023-06-09 20:43:16,571 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter
2023-06-09 20:43:16,574 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services
2023-06-09 20:43:16,616 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin
2023-06-09 20:43:16,637 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin
2023-06-09 20:43:16,681 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241006: Stopped embedded web server
2023-06-09 20:43:16,682 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.28.0 [4c0536c4-067e-11ee-8668-646c806f3233] stopped, uptime 8.807 seconds
```

**`broker.xml` of master node**:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>localhost</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      
      <!-- if you want to retain your journal uncomment this following configuration.

      This will allow your system to keep 7 days of your data, up to 10G. Tweak it accordingly to your use case and capacity.

      it is recommended to use a separate storage unit from the journal for performance considerations.

      <journal-retention-directory period="7" unit="DAYS" storage-limit="10G">data/retention</journal-retention-directory>

      You can also enable retention by using the argument journal-retention on the `artemis create` command -->



      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 3.05 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 328000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>328000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      
      <page-sync-timeout>328000</page-sync-timeout>


      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

      The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
      You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

      <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->

      <!-- the maximum number of messages accepted before entering full address mode.
           if global-max-size is specified the full address mode will be specified by whatever hits it first. -->
      <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->


         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>

        <connectors>
                <!-- master connector -->
              <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
                <!-- slave connector -->
              <connector name="artemis-slave1">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
              <connector name="artemis-slave2">tcp://localhost:61618</connector>
        </connectors>

        <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>artemis-slave1</connector-ref>
                <connector-ref>artemis-slave2</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

    <ha-policy>
             <replication>
                <master>
                   <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
                </master>
             </replication>
    </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

            <!-- if max-size-bytes and max-size-messages were both enabled, the system will enter into paging
                 based on the first attribute to hits the maximum value -->
            <!-- limit for the address in bytes, -1 means unlimited -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>

            <!-- limit for the address in messages, -1 means unlimited -->
            <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

            <!-- the size of each file on paging. Notice we keep files in memory while they are in use.
                 Lower this setting if you have too many queues in memory. -->
            <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

            <!-- limit how many messages are read from paging into the Queue. -->
            <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>

            <!-- limit how much memory is read from paging into the Queue. -->
            <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->
   </core>
</configuration>
```

**`jolokia-access.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!-- This policy file controls the Jolokia JMX-HTTP bridge security options for the web console.
   see: https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html -->
<restrict>

    <cors>
        <!-- Allow cross origin access from localhost ... -->
        <allow-origin>*</allow-origin>


        <!-- Options from this point on are auto-generated by Create.java from the Artemis CLI -->
        <!-- Check for the proper origin on the server side, too -->
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>

</restrict>
```

**`bootstrap.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
   <!-- artemis.URI.instance is parsed from artemis.instance by the CLI startup.
        This is to avoid situations where you could have spaces or special characters on this URI -->
   <server configuration="file:/D:/artemis-cluster/master-slave/master/etc//broker.xml"/>

   <!-- The web server is only bound to localhost by default -->
   <web path="web" rootRedirectLocation="console">
       <binding uri="http://localhost:8161">
           <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
           <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
           <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
       </binding>
   </web>
</broker>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that everything was working fine yesterday combined with the stack-trace from the log you pasted indicates that the problem is specifically within your Windows environment - i.e. *something* is already using the host & port you've configured:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:141) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.28.0.jar:?]
```

The broker itself can't really do anything about this. It delegates the binding operation to Netty and Netty, in turn, delegates this to the JVM. The JVM then asks the operating system (i.e. Windows in this case) if it can bind to the configured host & port and the OS is denying the JVM access since something else is already using it.

You likely have another instance of ActiveMQ Artemis running on port `61616` in the background which you need to shut down. In any case, you need to stop whatever process is using the configured host & port combination or choose a different host & port combination that isn't being used by anything else.

Deleting any or all of the `data`, `log`, and `tmp` folders won't have any impact on this issue.

Changing the port for the `artemis` `acceptor` in `broker.xml` should resolve the issue assuming you choose a port which is not also being used by another service.

Creating a new broker won't help since it will still be using the default hosts & ports.

Using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` won't help since they are effectively the same thing.

Even though you checked if any service is running on port `61616` and didn't find anything the stack-trace indicates that there is, in fact, something running on port `61616`.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921846/activemq-artemis-not-starting-on-windows-10-failed-to-bind-acceptor) which is similar to your issue.

Comment: I have tried below command but none of the process is working on 61616 --------->netstat -ano | findstr :61616

Comment: Even though you checked if any service is running on port `61616` and didn't find anything the stack-trace indicates that there is, in fact, something running on port `61616`. Otherwise the OS wouldn't prevent the JVM from binding to it.

Comment: So how to kill then services on 61616

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps try rebooting. Personally I would recommend avoiding Windows if at all possible.

Comment: I have already restarted my laptop 15-20 times

Comment: The fact that everything was working fine yesterday combined with the stack-trace from the log you pasted indicates that the problem is specifically within your Windows environment - i.e. _something_ is already using the host & port you've configured. You can either eliminate whatever is using the configured host & port **or** configure the broker to use a different host and/or port which isn't being used by anything else. I avoid using Windows whenever possible so I can't give you advice on how to track down this phantom/rogue process.